# Is UCP in Oracle Maven Repository?

Tags: oracle, maven, repository, ucp

Trying to build an OJDBC app via Gradle, we can find com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc7:12.1.0.2 in the Oracle Maven Repository at https://maven.oracle.com, but we can't get com.oracle.jdbc:ucp:12.1.0.2.  This 'tutorial' link from Oracle suggests it should be available: https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/entry/how_to_get_oracle_jdbc

Following the instructions in the article, using Maven and a Hello, World project, Maven pulls down ojdbc7.jar but it "could not find artifact com.oracle.jdbc:ucp:jar:12.1.0.2".

Is anyone else able to get it via Maven download?  Is the GAV correct?

We have retrieved the file to deposit into a local repository of "things you can't get from Maven", so we have a workaround.  But it seems like this should be available, and so should need to be in such a repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UCP is available on Oracle Maven Repository.   The GAV is

```
<groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
<artifactId>ucp</artifactId>
<version>12.1.0.2</version>
```

I just tested downloading the UCP POM file from https://www.oracle.com/content/secure/maven/content/com/oracle/jdbc/ucp/12.1.0.2/ucp-12.1.0.2.pom and it worked fine.

Please make sure to use your Oracle usename and password correctly.

Comment: Thank you.  I notice it's a different URL (I had seen it referenced elsehwere and even tried it, but I didn't get it to work.)  This link is working for me too, and both the poms and the jars for ucp and ojdbc7 were available.  So they must be there...  Thanks again.